# Prevent to download pdf using embed tag

Tags: html, pdf

I'm using php, I'm creating a detailed view page of a profile, which has a pdf document, I use the `embed` tag to display it, but when opened it does not display the pdf file and Automatically download the file. Therefore the user can not see the pdf file displayed.

```
<embed src="/vh/assets/image/java.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="500" height="500"/>
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm using Google PDF viewer for that and it's running very well ! The src should be something like `http://docs.google.com/gview?url=YOUR_PDF_URL`

Comment: thank you, but my site is so that users can upload their documents, I use the move_uploaded_file () method in php to save that document and then retrieve and display it, you know it?

Answer (score 1):

#### PDF documents are not supported as a src in the HTML `<embed>` tag.

You can get around this issue by using the Google Chrome PDF viewer as the embed `src.

```
<embed
  src="https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=http://yourdomain.com/vh/assets/image/java.pdf"
  width="500"
  height="500"
/>
```

Note that your url in the `src` cannot be relative `/vh/assets/image/java.pdf`, it must be the full url `http://yourdomain.com/vh/assets/image/java.pdf`.

---

There also exist some third party libaries such as [PDF.JS](http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/).

Comment: thank you, but my site is so that users can upload their documents, I use the move_uploaded_file () method in php to save that document and then retrieve and display it, you know it?

Comment: Ah I understand, I don't know it unfortunately. In your case maybe you should look into a third party library, good luck!

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to [w3schools embed tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_embed.asp),It is an html single tag,I can display pdf normally in chrome and firefox.Maybe you can check if your src is correct.

Answer (score -1):

You can try below snippet **#toolbar=0** helps disabling the options

```
<embed id="myObject1" src="file:///C:/Downloads/OoPdfFormExample.pdf#toolbar=0" type="application/pdf" width="1000px" height="600px">
```

This will disable download, print and other option of pdf viewer on browser
[image]